# Cakephp pagination ajax messes up the view

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, pagination

So after a very long time and ALOT of hassle ive finally made my ajax pagination work (sort of)

Now my html looks like this:

```
    <?php
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'evalScripts' => true,
));
?>

<div class="portlet box green Report index" id="content">
<div class="portlet-title">
    <div class="caption"><i class="icon-globe"></i>Report Summary</div>
    <div class="tools">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"></a>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="portlet-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width"
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Offer.name','Offer'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Stat.clicks','Clicks'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Stat.conversions','Conversion'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Stat.payout','Payout'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Stat.ltr', 'What-isThis?'); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Stat.cpc','Expected E-CPC'); ?></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="report_data">
                <?php foreach ($table['Report']['data']['data'] as $res): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Offer']['name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Stat']['clicks']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Stat']['conversions']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Stat']['payout']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Stat']['ltr']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><?php echo h($res['Stat']['cpc']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            <ul>
                <?php if ($this->Paginator->hasPrev()): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->first(__('First')) ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('Prev'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled')) ?></li>
                <?php
                endif;

                echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('currentTag' => 'span', 'currentClass' => 'active',
                    'separator' => false, 'tag' => 'li', 'modulus' => 5));

                if ($this->Paginator->hasNext()):
                    ?>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('Next'), array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled')) ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->last(__('Last')) ?></li>
                <?php endif ?>
            </table>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

sadly i cant show you a picture (it says im lacking reputation) but it seems that when i press to paginate it puts the content of the site into the div block meaning that the view gets messed up alot!

Can anyone tell me why it is doing this and how i can fix it?

i have tried moving the id='content' around to different div or table blocks but with no success

**Cake version 2.3**

**My Index action**

```
    public function index()
{
    if($this->request->is('ajax'))
    {
        $this->layout('ajax');
    }else{

    $this->layout = 'client_layout';
    }
    $startDate = $this->request->data['startDateTime'];
    $endDate = $this->request->data['endDateTime'];
    if($startDate == null || $startDate == '' ){
        $startDate = date('y-m-d');
        $endDate = date('y-m-d');
    }
    array_push($this->paginate['conditions']['Stat.date']['values'], $startDate, $endDate);
    $this->set('table', $this->paginate());
}
```

**Update**

Okay so in my controller i added the following:

```
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->autoLayout = true;
        $this->autoRender = true;
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }else{
    $this->layout = 'client_layout';
    }
```

Now this helped however it isnt 100% as it should be, now it is adding a div block ontop of the table here is some HTML of what it looks like:

```
    <div id="updateTable">
<div class="portlet box red"> <-- VERY BAD!!
<div class="portlet-title">
<div class="portlet-body">
</div>
<div id="updateTable">
```

**Please note i also changed the id to updateTable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller action where pagination link is going check for request is in ajax or not. if request made via ajax then tell controller not to add header and other css code.

```
if($this->request->is('ajax'))
{ 
      $this->layout('ajax');
}
```

Comment: if i add this to my controller i get an internal error (in the javascript debugger) il add my index to my question

Comment: @Marc do you have ajax.ctp file inside views layout folder..?

Comment: Yes i do which cointains <?php echo $this->fetch('content');?>

Comment: @Marc well you are repeating `DOM ID` of `updateTable`...do not repeat same ID

Comment: the funny thing is i am not repeating it in my code it must be generated by the javascript (or what do i know :P :S)

Answer (score 0):

Your html markup is not valid. The table-element is closed too late, just move

```
</table>
```

before

```
<ul>
```

and remove last div-tag.

As far as I know you don't have to check for ajax-requests manually. If RequestHandler is included in the components, the corresponding layout should be selected automatically.

Simply add the following to your AppController:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```